# Before save model check some field

Tags: django

I need to check if other models already created, have a field filled .
If another model has the field with any value, the current model that attempts to create should not happen. And if possible send an error message.

This is my current code:

```
class Video(models.Model):
  #####
  # Fields of model
  #####

  def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, *args, **kwargs):
    some_video = Video.objects.all().filter(field_boolean=True).first()
    if not some_video:
      # Save current model
      super(Video, self).save(force_insert, force_update, *args, **kwargs)
    else:
      # avoid save method for the current model created and send error message
```

What am I doing wrong or what I'm missing? What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Mi code not work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Firstly, you do not need to use `all()` and `filter()` together. Secondly, use [exists()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#exists) instead of `first()`. It returns `True` if the `QuerySet` contains any results, and `False` if not. This tries to perform the query in the simplest and fastest way possible.

```
class Video(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    field_boolean = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if Video.objects.filter(field_boolean=True).exists():
            print('Video with field_boolean=True exists')
        else:
            super(Video, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: The method save, also works with method update? The variable self, Is the current row that is to be created?